# Question about limits, continuity and absolute values.

Tags: limits

Suppose we have $|f(x)| \leq |g(x)|$ and  $g(0) = 0$ and $g$ continuous at $0$. Prove that $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Any hints would be really appreciated!

Comment: anything else that you know about $g$?

Comment: g is continuous at 0!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Use $|g(x)-0|<\epsilon\implies|f(x)-0|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Try squeeze Theorems.

Note that without continuity of $g$, the statement is not true in general.

Example:

Let $$f(x)=g(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x=0 \\ 1 & x \neq 0 \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Or you could prove it by contraposition. Suppose $f$ is discontinuous at $0$. Then you find a sequence $(x_n)_n$ such that $\ldots$ and since $|f(x_n)|\leq |g(x_n)|$ we conclude $\ldots$ and therefore $g$ is discontinuous at $0$ contrary to the assumption that $g$ is continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$|f(x)| \le |g(x)|$;

$0 \le |f(0)| \le |g(0)| = 0 \Rightarrow$

$|f(0)| = 0$.

$g$ is continuous at $x= 0$:

For $ \epsilon \gt 0$ there exist a $\delta \gt 0$, such that

$|x| \lt \delta$ implies  $|g(x)| \lt \epsilon$.

Choose this $\delta$ to show continuity at $x=0$ for $f$.

Recall $f(0) = g(0) =0$.

For $|x| \lt \delta $ we have

$|f(x)| \le |g(x)| \lt \epsilon$.